# Why is the air denser at low heights?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science, air, density, fluid-statics

I don't know if it applies to all fluids , but why is air denser at lower heights ?

Answer (score 1):

As firstly noted by Torricelli, "air weighs and we live at the bottom of an ocean of air". Lower heights therefore have more weight over them and feel more pressure. Since air is compressible the larger the weight on a portion of air, the larger its compression and therefore the large its density.

Liquids on the other hand are in general approximately incompressible thus the change in density with height is approximately zero.

Comment: Thank u . And in case we don't have a weight over air , then it won't be pressed so it won't be denser at the bottom. So it depends on how much there are clouds in the sky and u know other stuff. Right?

Comment: The weight mentioned is the weight of the air itself.  There is nothing to do with clouds in the sky. You could consider for example what would happen if there was no gravity hence no weight. In this case, yes, the density would be constant.

Comment: Ah okay. What are all forces acting on air other than the weight?

Answer (score 0):

Air pressure is the mass of the atmosphere times the $g$, or just the weight of the air, so the lower you go, the more air is pushing down